# TPL .ContinueWith priority when executing a lot of tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am trying to do a lot of asynchronous work in a certain order (FIFO).

Here's the code:

```
foreach (var header in headers)
   _broker.SendAsync(header.request)
          .ContinueWith(t => _broker2.SendAsync(t.Result.request2));
```

The problem I am having is that no Continuation happens until all _broker.SendAsync are completed. I'd like it to work more sequentially, which is to run ContinueWith as soon as any of the brokers finished sending.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "all _broker.SendAsync are completed"? what type is `_broker`?

Comment: Does the type `_broker` is support multiple calls to `.SendAsync`?

Comment: _broker is a custom implementation. It is thread safe and does support multiple calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always I suggest you use [`TPL Dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It lets you declare a clear sequential flow and let the `TPL` handle all the nitty-gritty details behind. You can configure a degree of parallelism and a bounded capacity to make it more robust.

```
var first = new TransformBlock<T, U>(header => _broker.SendAsync(header.request));
var second = new ActionBlock<U>(result => _broker2.SendAsync(result.request2));

first.LinkTo(second);

foreach (var header in headers)
    await first.SendAsync();
```

Answer (score 5):

`ContinueWith` is triggered as soon as the antecedent is ready. In your code there is nothing forcing sequential execution. In fact, how could the TPL possibly know that it is being called from a `foreach` loop and delay execution? It cannot know.

Probably, you are misinterpreting what you are seeing. Maybe `broker2` internally forces serial execution? Impossible to tell without further information.

Consider moving the loop body into a helper function and using `async/await` there. Easier to use.